# Recyclerview onclick on a null object reference

Tags: java

I want to pass Recyclerview onclick to show image
I can display successfully Recyclerview，but when I click the app close

Error message

```
Process: com.example.twjdsintern, PID: 11497
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' 
on a null object reference
    at com.example.twjdsintern.splash.adapter.RecyclerAdapter.onClick(RecyclerAdapter.java:40)
```

my RecyclerAdapter

This problem seems to be here

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(mEvent != null){
        mEvent.onClick((int)v.getTag());
    }
}
```

Comment: If `v.getTag()` returns `null` (I assume the return type is `Integer`) then the unboxing (due to the cast to `int`) will fail with a NPE.